# HTML help for mouseover split button image

Tags: image, split, mouseover

I am a neophyte at HTML as my question may reflect, but I could use some help. I have a table cell that contains what looks line one button but is actually two side by side. My goal is when the one on the left is hovered over in the box above an image is displayed. When I move to the one on the right another one is displayed. On a mouseoff in both cases a default image is displayed. I can get the left half to work perfectly, but cannot seem to get the HTML code for the right half correct. To to this go to http://www.greensphotoimages.com and look at the button "About Cori About Ron" and hover over the "About Cori". The code I am using in table are as follows:

I would really appreciate anyones help! Much thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I placed two buttons in the same span and used CSS to align them together. For example:

`<span class="x-split-button">
  <button class="x-button x-button-main"> About Ron</button>
  <button class="x-button x-button-main">About Cori</button>
</span>`

I have included the codepen so you can see the code and the [DEMO](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/KpadaW)

Comment: Much thanks for this! I will need to study it since I have not dealt with @ABrowBowGeniousCSS before. Does it go above in the Header Section? Also, can you offer any help regarding where I would insert the code calling out the image swap? Look at my site and the recent update and hopefully that will help. Thanks again.

Comment: You would use the same JavaScript your using just give each button an id so that onMouseOver the image shows. You can use CSS to make the code above look like your current button set up.